# Is an application of the growth of the number of $k$-dimensional stabilser codes known, where $k \ge 1$?

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code, applications

For the case when $k=0$, that is, when the stabiliser code is (in fact) a stabiliser state, then many applications are known.

Some of them are listed below.

1. Resource theory of magic: measures of magic are often cast as optimization problems over the convex stabiliser polytope. Stabiliser states are the extremal points of this polytope, and thus, knowing their number gives one a sense of the tractability (or lack thereof) of the optimisation problem.
2. Classical simulation of stabiliser operations: one is required to know the number of classical bits (or dits) to store a stabiliser state and keep track of it.
3. Frame potential for stabiliser states: the number was used by Kueng and Gross to prove that for qubit systems, stabiliser states are $3$-state designs.
4. de Finnetti theorem for stabiliser states..
5. Quantum contextuality, optimal verification of stabiliser states and study of Wigner functions.

These are listed in Sec 1A to Sec 1E in a recent work: [Counting stabiliser codes for arbitrary dimension](https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.01449).

Are there similar applications known for the case when $k \ge 1$? Does the growth of this number play a role in the complexity of similar problems?

Comment: The set of rank $k$ stabilizer codes is still informationally complete. Stabilizer code projectors are, up to normalization, mixed stabilizer states and occur when performing a partial trace on stabilizer states. This plays a role e.g. in this simulation algorithm https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.12223 Operators of the form $UP$ where $U$ is Clifford and $P$ is a stabilizer code projector correspond to $2n$-qudit stabilizer states under Choi isomorphism. They are the Kraus operators of completely stabilizer-preserving maps.

Comment: Yes, but do you need to know the cardinality of the set of rank k stabiliser codes for  the purpose that is achieved in this simulation algorithm?

Comment: Probably in the same sense as you need it for 1). I don't see where the cardinality enters for your applications, except for 1) and 4). BTW, I think most of these applications do not generalize to non-prime(-power) dimensions.

Comment: //Probably in the same sense as you need it for 1).// 

With 1. (and the rest:2,3,4,5) the figure given by Gross (Hudson's thm) was explicitly used in making arguments or during the course of derivations. Be it an order of magnitude based argument or something more... still it was explicitly used and referred to. In that sense, it played a role.

But with the simulation algorithm you posted, the cardinality of [[n,k]] codes for arbitrary k (which Gross computed) doesn't seem to be used (I scanned for it but didn't find it). 

I'm looking for such explicit applications (if possible).

Comment: //BTW, I think most of these applications do not generalize to non-prime(-power) dimensions.//

I think that in the case of 1. and 2.: there'd be applications similar to the prime cases: the order of magnitude argument of the stabilizer states works in both cases.

For 3. and 4.: it is not guaranteed that they're readily useful, yes. 

That being said, on the whole, I'd still feel like saying that the the growth of the number of stabilizer states plays a role in the complexity of certain issues.

Question's whether there's anything to suggest this is so for no. of [[n,k]] codes too?

Comment: Perhaps there is an application for it. In this twitter thread Stefano Gogioso asks the question: how can one sample from a uniform distribution over all stabilizer groups of rank k (k independent generators). The reason for interest in this question is unknown, but one may anticipate that it would find some use. 

https://twitter.com/StefanoGogioso/status/1589997845087604736